# VS Code Extension LSP Variable completions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, compiler-construction, ide, language-server-protocol

Please show me a simple example of how to do autocompletion for example of a variable. The user created a variable with some name and type, value. After the user enters for example **var::** and then the names of variables that exist appear. I still don't know how to make resources from programming language libraries recognized too.

Example of variable assignment:
`mut name T value`

I tried writing in a class from registerCompletionProvider.
I need to write this in Typescript.